# how to autoplay sound when I open the app?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm new to xcode .I want to autoplay a sound when I open the app . I put the code in viewDidLoad but when I open other view and go back the sound play again .how can fix this problem ??

Answer (score 1):

You could set a boolean variable to true after the first time you play it. Something like this:

```
bool soundPlayed = FALSE;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // play your sound
    soundPlayed = true;
}
```

Or, in your AppDelegate.m, there's probably something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You could try doing it in there, too.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`or in `- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application`. If you use it in `didBecomeActive` the app will play the sound if you background it and open it again.
Playing a sound file goes like this:

```
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                           pathForResource:@"click"
                                           ofType:@"caf"]];
AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
[click play];
[click release];
```